# VisualStateManager on Flyout not highlighting entire area

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a VisualStateManager that controls the background color when the pointer is over the item. The problem is, it doesn't highlight the entire area, just a small portion around the text and icon. Here's my code:

[Not fully highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VElLA.png)

```
<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <MenuFlyout>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Click="DeleteMenuItemClick">
            <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0">
                            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Delete" Margin="10,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition To="PointerOver"
                                                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Flyout" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                                                To="{StaticResource SystemAltHighColor}" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="Flyout" 
                                             Color="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            </SolidColorBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
        </MenuFlyoutItem>
    </MenuFlyout>
</FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

EDIT:

Thanks everyone for the answers. I'll look into those solutions when I can; I did end up doing something a little different - making the area a bit bigger so you can see the highlight by adding padding. It's not quite what I wanted, which is why I'll look into these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't highlight the entire area because you are using Visual State in `MenuFlyoutItem` and the highlight area is the area of your `MenuFlyoutItem`.

You can see this in Visual Studio's **Live Visual Tree**. To see this clearly, we can run the app in **Simulator** and check **"Display layout adorners in the running application"** in Live Visual Tree. Then you will see the size of the `MenuFlyoutItem`.

[image]

When selecting `MenuFlyoutItem` in Live Visual Tree, its area will be blue. It's not clear in my picture, you can try it yourself.

So to highlight the entire area, we need let the `MenuFlyoutItem` fill the full `MenuFlyoutPresenter` and to do this, we need edit the style of `MenuFlyout` by setting `MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle`. You can find the default `MenuFlyoutPresenter` style at [MenuFlyoutPresenter styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt299139.aspx).

To set `MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle`, we can copy the default style from website or in Visual Studio, select the "**[MenuFlyout]**" in "**Document Outline**" and right click, then select "**Edit Additional Templates**" →  "**Edit MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle**" → "**Edit a Copy...**".

In the style, we need remove the `Margin` in `ItemsPresenter` by setting it to `0`

```
<ItemsPresenter Margin="0"/>
```

Then there will be no margin around the `MenuFlyoutItem`. However this is not enough because `MenuFlyoutPresenter` has a 32 min height:

```
<x:Double x:Key="MenuFlyoutThemeMinHeight">32</x:Double>
```

If the height of `MenuFlyoutItem` is less than 32, it also can't highlight the entire area. To solve this, you can set `MinHeight` property to `0`.

```
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
```

Or increase the height of `MenuFlyoutItem` like setting `Margin` in your `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,8">
    <SymbolIcon Margin="10,0" Symbol="Delete" />
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The complete MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle may like following:

```
<Style x:Key="MyMenuFlyoutPresenterStyle" TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPresenterThemePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="MenuFlyoutPresenterScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" MinWidth="{Binding TemplateSettings.FlyoutContentMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="0" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <Border x:Name="MenuFlyoutPresenterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question and showed me an element of VS I hadn't used. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

edit the style of MenuFlyout and you will achieve what you want,
I will do it something like that

```
<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Style>
                    </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Click="DeleteMenuItemClick">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                                <Grid>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0">
                                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Delete" Margin="10,0" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualTransition To="PointerOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Flyout" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource SystemAltHighColor}" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Grid.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="Flyout" Color="{TemplateBinding Background}"></SolidColorBrush>
                                    </Grid.Background>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

Comment: Thank you vijay; this help as well as Jay Zuo's answer.